# countable additivity for a collection of algebra imply countable subadditivity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

hi all does countable additivity for a collection of algebra imply countable subadditivity for an Algebra? if so, what is so special about being Algebra that makes countable subadditivity automatically holds when countable additivity holds?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, trying to make sense of this question, suppose we have $\mathcal{A}$ which is an algebra of subsets of some set $X$, and a countably additive function $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to [0,+\infty]$, say.
Then indeed $\mu$ is countably subadditive:

let $A_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be any family of sets from $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathcal{A}$.

Then define $B_0 = A_0$, $B_n = A_n \setminus \cup_{i=0}^{n-1} A_i$ for $n \ge 1$. The fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra (!!) means that all $B_n \in \mathcal{A}$ as well (algebras are closed under finite unions, intersections and set differences).

Also, if $n \neq m$: $B_n \cap B_m = \emptyset$ (suppose $n < m$ WLOG, then $x \in B_n \cap B_m$ implies $x \in B_n$ so $x \in A_n$ and $x \in B_m$ so $x \notin A_n$ (it's one of the sets we substract from $A_m$ to form $B_m$!), contradiction, so the intersection is empty). So the $B_n$ form a pairwise dijsoint family , which is part one of their raison d'être. Part two is:

$$\bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n A_n$$

The left to right inclusion is clear, as $B_k \subseteq A_k$ for all $k$, So take $x \in \bigcup_n A_n$, and let $m$ be the minimal index in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in A_m$ (there exists at least one such index, so there is a smallest one). Then $x \notin A_i$ for $i < m$ by minimality so either $x \in A_0 = B_0$ (if $m=0$) or $x \in A_m \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{m-1} A_i = B_m$ otherwise. So $x \in \bigcup_n B_n$ and we have equality.

Now the fact that $\mu$ is countably additive gives the middle equality in

$$\mu(\bigcup_n A_n) = \mu(\bigcup_n B_n) = \sum_n \mu(B_n) \le \sum_n \mu(A_n)$$

where the last inequality follows from $B_n \subseteq A_n$ so $\mu(B_n) \le \mu(A_n)$.

See how we use the algebra properties of $\mathcal{A}$ to construct the $B_n$? They have to be in $\mathcal{A}$ or $\mu$ would not be defined on them.

Comment: Hi Henno, thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. But I just have one more questions, when I have a set of Algebra of X say denoted as $A_1, A_2, ..., A_i,...$, does it mean for any subset say called it $A$ of the X,  it is possible to approximate $A$ as close as we want by only using the set in the Algebra? does it mean for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a collection of sets in the Algebra say denoted as $A_1, A_2, ..., A_i,...$ , and the union of those sets can cover the set A arbitrarily such that $\mu( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \setminus{A} )\leq \epsilon$?

Comment: @john_w no, this need not hold. Nor is $\mu$ guaranteed to be defined on that subset. It might hold for some algebras and some $A$ though, it depends.